# How can I start the text on the left marquee correctly?

Tags: jquery, marquee

How can I do the content start to the left and no to the right?
I try do it with float left and it not work.

```js
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    duration: 5000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 10,
    //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: 'left',
    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
    duplicated: true
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Change `direction: 'right'`

Comment: @ArunKumar i want start the text on the left no start the text on the right

Answer (score 0):

To make your text scroll right (i.e. from left to right), use `behavior="scroll"` and `direction="right"`

```js
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    duration: 5000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 10,
    //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: "right",
    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
    duplicated: true
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<div class="marquee">TEST</div>
```

Comment: I want start the text on the left and from the left continue the text to the left and show then for the right and continue the move